Chain sed with xargs
Simple but seems (to me) unsolvable problem.
Have a very simple text file with few lines - here is example
dummy_file.txt
Line 1a
Line 2a
Line 3a

This file is actually a .log which is continuously appended. I want to replace the single quote character (') in the line with something else let's say with double quote char (") and pass the replaced line to xargs. Each command in part works fine but when I combine both is "hangs" - here is my example:
tail -f dummy_file.txt | sed  --expression="s/'/\"/g"

Above works as expected - when new line is added to the file it replaces the single quote with double
tail -f dummy_file.txt | xargs  -I {} echo "Hello {}"

Above works as expected - when new line is added to the file it is passed to the "echo" and the "Hello" is added to the line.
But when I combine both it hangs (shows nothing)
tail -f dummy_file.txt | sed  --expression="s/'/\"/g" | xargs  -I {} echo "Hello {}"

In reality it will be something like:

tail -f /var/log/messages | sed  --expression="s/'/"/g" | xargs  -I
{} echo "Hello {}" > new_file.sql

Any ideas what could be the problem and how to solve it?

Why show a dummy file that doesn't contain any quotes when the question is about converting quotes?

There are no single quotes in your example data!?

I know it, the question is different - how to make it work, in the future I can have single quota too.

For a start, provide a [mcve], including example data and precise instructions how to run them. One thing I'd also try is to replace tail -f with cat for now, because there might be some buffering going on. Please [edit] your question to include that info.

What do you want me to do - to explain you how to create a .text file with 3 lines? how to append a line to a file - if you don't know this I have doubts you can help me.

well, if you would change s/'/"/g by s/L/X/g then it would make sense with your input data, but I think I understand and reproduce your question. I guess it has something to do with buffering of stdout/stdin at some point in the pipe

What's the real command being executed by xargs? sed itself is perfectly capable of prefixing every line with Hello.

The problem is that sed is buffering its output -- that is, it processes the lines it gets from tail, but doesn't bother to print it to its output (the pipe to xargs) until it has a full buffer. If it got an end-of-file on its input, it'd know there's no more coming, and output what it has, but tail -f doesn't do that (it's waiting for more to be added to the file), so sed doesn't have any idea it should stop waiting and output what it has.
Solution: If you're using GNU sed (as the --expression options suggests), you can add its -u (or --unbuffered) option to make it flush output more often. Under BSD sed, you'd use the -l ("line-buffered") option instead.

Found the solution - for those who are interested here it is:

tail -f dummy_file.txt | stdbuf -oL sed  --expression="s/'/^/g" |
xargs  -I {} echo "Hello {}"

